# computeExpression with saqlExpression using Date field issue

Tags: einstein-analytics

I'm trying to create a computeExpression in my Dataflow to calculate: **how many days have passed since a given date until now**
and add this calculation as a new field into the dataset.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
"ComExp_UpToDate": {
    "action": "computeExpression",
    "parameters": {
      "source": "My_Last_Node",
      "mergeWithSource": true,
      "computedFields": [
        {
          "defaultValue": "0",
          "name": "u2d_Field",
          "saqlExpression": "daysBetween(​toDate(namespace__CustomField_Date__c, \"yyyy-MM-dd\"​), now())",
          "label": "Days until now",
          "type": "Numeric",
          "precision": 16,
          "scale": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

I'm getting the following error:
Error executing node ComExp_UpToDate: invalid field expression daysBetween(​toDate(namespace__CustomField_Date__c, "yyyy-MM-dd"​), now()) for field 'u2d_Field': Error at position 14: Unexpected character 'â' (0Bw58000000DIavCAG_0Bq58000000LAlECAW)

I've tried a few other options and all failed:

- Different date formats: "yyyy-M-d"
- Using _Year, _Month, _Day dimensions, but they're not created until registering the dataset
- I have also created a computeExpression to transform this Date field into a Text field to check the date format, and it's showing "yyyy-MM-dd" but maybe internally it's different.

**Notes:**

- namespace__CustomField_Date__c is a Date field
- I don't think the solution should be to create a formula field in the Custom Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured out the problem.

The SAQL expression is fine so if anyone wants to use it **do not copy and paste**, this was my mistake in the first place.

The SAQL Expression in the question has some zero-width spaces. I wasn't able to see this char using Sublime Text nor Notepad++ so I had to go back to my roots and open the file using vi editor.
[image: Zero-Width Spaces]